# Play store not allowing to publish beta version with target sdk 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

i am trying to upload release as BETA version but every time it show this 
error

> it is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M
>   permissions  (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style
>   permissions (target  SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from
>   version 28 (target SDK  23) to version 25 (target SDK 21). [image]

the gradle im using currently is

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 'N'

    versionCode 29
    versionName '1.12.5'
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

please see the attach image. I also add M permissions in my app and i am still can't publish beta version Why?
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: current im trying to publish Beta version with this gradle setting
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23

    versionCode 29
    versionName '1.12.5'
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

Comment: in android 6.0 appeared runtime permission http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: are you using app licensing in app?

Comment: i already add M permission, if i use target sdk 'N' i can't install my app on device @PeDuCKA

Comment: yes, im using App  Licensing @humayoonsiddique

Comment: I think you use older version api level as compare to app due to this may be its occur please try to change api level hope its help you in your problem @Aamir